# Is there a paper glue that is NOT dissolved by acetone?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solutions

Short version of the question: I need a spray-on glue that will stick paper to wood that isn't dissolved by acetone.

Long version: I am trying to glue paper on wood. It's a big sheet of paper and I need it stuck on throughout because then I cut the wood-with-paper-on-it into pieces with a laser cutter. Therefore, I'm using a spray glue that can cover the whole sheet of paper quickly and evenly. I have tried a couple different glues. After the pieces are cut, I want to spray an acrylic coating over the resulting pieces to seal them.

The process works except for one problem: if the acetone in the acrylic spray seeps through, it dissolves every glue I have tried. I try to go light with the acrylic, but more than 50% of my pieces end up with the paper coming loose from the wood. I can glue it back on later, but that means that the positioning of the paper is way less precise and the edge seal isn't there, making it susceptible to water damage.

Are there any glues anyone knows of that meet this challenge? 
(I suppose, alternatively, is there an inexpensive sealant that doesn't use acetone? But I know the acrylic will hold up to the abuse these playing pieces are going to take, so I am hesitant to swap out that part of my process.)

Comment: Silicate glue (AKA "liquid glass") might do.

Comment: Mucilage and casein type glues (e.g. Elmer's) are two types of water based glue that are more likely to be resistant to the acetone in the acrylic varnish spray. But they do not come in spray-on form. However, if you diluted them with water and applied them with a compressed air sprayer you should get an even coating. Alternatively you could keep the spray adhesive as is and apply a water-based acrylic coat at the end--again by using a sprayer if necessary.

Comment: @iad22agp I'm going to attempt thicker paper for the printing as my first "work around," but I'll fall back to this if I don't get any better posts. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can try to use is tape to put under the glue. This may stop the acetone from seeping through. Not quite sure but maybe if you really need it done. Also, Elmer's glue does offer a spray on version regardless of what some say on your comments.

Comment: A spray-on Elmer's? I've never seen such a thing. I just now tried a search experiment... it's funny -- if I search for "spray on glue", the Elmer's (or any non-acetone glue) doesn't show up even in 2 pages of search results... but (thanks to your answer) if I search for "spray on Elmer's" explicitly, there it is! This may be exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome! Good luck